# How to uncheck a specific row in Kendo Grid select column in ASP.NET MVC using JavaScript and jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, kendo-ui, grid

I have a Kendo Grid in my ASP.NET MVC 5 project. One of the columns is a select column and I am trying to deselect a checkbox if it satisfies a sepecific condition. I have managed to deselect the checkbox. The issue is it is only changing the UI but not removing the deselected from `this.select()`. Just uncheck the specific row that made the condition = true and keep the ones that are false selected.

In summary, if the condition = true, I want to uncheck the box, remove it from `this.select()`, remove it from `this.selectedKeyNames()` and remove it from `this._selectIds()`. NOT Delete the row from the table in the UI.

***The code below is not the actual code I am using but something similar to it. The code below is probably not going to work.***

```
function onChange(e) {
   var selectedRows = this.select();
   for(var i = 0; i < selectedRows.length; i++){
       selectedRows[i].find("input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked', false);
       if( 2 > 6) {
          alert("You can't select this");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the [`change`](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/events/change) event cannot be prevented within the event handler, so you could add a `dataBound` event handler and attach a click handler to the select checkboxes. If the condition is met - stop the propagation of the event:

```
        dataBound: function(){
          var grid = this;
          grid.tbody.find('tr .k-select-checkbox').on('click', function(e){
            var dataItem = grid.dataItem($(this).closest("tr"));
            if(dataItem.Discontinued){
              $(this).prop('checked', !$(this).prop('checked'));
              e.stopImmediatePropagation();
              kendo.alert(`${dataItem.ProductName} is discontinued, you cannot select it!`)
            }
          })
        }
```

In this [example](https://dojo.telerik.com/obojuQoB) you cannot select discontinued items.